# Replace Fira Math calligraphics by hfbrsy10?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm using Fira Math in a xelatex-compiled document. Unfortunately, Fira Math does not have calligraphic letters (`\mathcal`).

I would therefore like to replace them by these
[image: mathcal]
which I found in `hfbrsy10.pfb`.

I tried to do so using

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathcal,extension=.pfb]{hfbrsy10}
```

but `fontspec` says the font cannot be found. Which makes sense, since `fontspec` uses OpenType fonts, while this one is Type 1.

Is there an OpenType font I can use for this, or another method to replace the calligraphic letters by these?

---

I would also be interested in recommendations which other calligraphics to use with Fira Math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `\mathcal` to use the same font as `cmbright` does.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

abc $abc\mathcal{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I now found that there is an OpenType version of CM Bright, `cmunb*`. Would it be possible to use that one instead? I wasn't able to find out which of the 6 files contains the calligraphics.